# I have problems with sync in meteor, trying to create a notification after successful payment.

Tags: meteor

I have problems with sync in meteor. I use paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs in my app. basically i want client send information(card number,cvc ...) to server by meteor method and and waiting server response (suscess or error). In server, i use api to create a payment and send it to paypal.

```
    Meteor.methods
      ({
      todo: function(creditCard)
        {PAYPAL_API.payment.create
           (creditCard, function (err, res) {})
        }
      });
```

As you can see , the api use callback function to continue execution with mean if i want to send server response to client  it doesn't work, always null 
Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having a clash of the typical Node.js way of doing things (callbacks) and the Meteor way of doing things (Fibers).

If you want to muddle thru, you could do something like this:

```
todo: function(creditCard)
{
   var res = null;
   PAYPAL_API.payment.create(creditCard,
     function (err, res) { t = res; }
   )
   while(!res) { sleep(1); }
   return res;
}
```

This might work, but it's probably wasteful of resources.

It would be better to re-structure the problem around Meteor reactivity. Either create your own reactive context, or just use the database: (you're saving the results to the DB already, right?)

```
todo: function(creditCard)
{
   PAYPAL_API.payment.create(creditCard,
     function (err, res) { MyDatabase.Update(blah, res); }
   )
}
```

Now, both your server and your client "move on" immediately. The client can 'listen' for his result via the database. You can make a "channel" for every user to get just their results. (Something like `if (Meteor.isServer) { Meteor.publish('mypayments', -> return Payments.find({user: Meteor.userId})) }`)